# Python psycopg2 debug cut off

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the problem that my PostgreSQL function call has the wrong parameters/types:

> function system.set_user_data(unknown, integer, unknown,
>   text[], text[], text[], text[], text[], text[], unknown, unknown,
>   boolean, boolean, unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer,
>   boolean, integer) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM
>   system.set_user_data('Thomas...
>                         ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

(I don't have access to the postgresql log to see the call there.)

But with "system.set_user_data('Thomas..." cut off, I can't see how the call would look like, to investigate, where the problem is exactly.

Is there a way, where I can print out the function_call, where I have the "SELECT * FROM (function_name)" and all input parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cursor.mogrify()`

```
print cursor.mogrify(my_query, (param1, param2))
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

But my guess is that you must cast 'Thomas' to text

```
SELECT * FROM system.set_user_data('Thomas'::text...
```

or to whatever the function is expecting